# code running as string need to convert it to float

Tags: python-3.x

i just need help to convert the input of the user to float thats all

thanks

```
def takenum(x,y):

    print("Your first number is " + x + " your second number is " + y)

    result = (x + y)

    print(result)

x = input("put your first number: " )

y = input("Put your second number: " )

takenum(x, y)
```

Comment: did you google the title to your question (string need to convert it to float)? `x = float('3.5')`...

Comment: yeah its sound funny but i tried to convert this code to float in a lot of ways (im on this little thing for about an hour) its sound funny but yeah couldnt found the answer to convert it into float

Comment: Use `x = float( input("Put your first number: " )` and same for `y` and it should work.

Comment: yeah i treid this and thats the error i get and im not sure why

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shahar/PycharmProjects/ShaharProject/Shahar.py", line 11, in <module>
    takenum(x, y)
  File "C:/Users/Shahar/PycharmProjects/ShaharProject/Shahar.py", line 6, in takenum
    print("Your first number is " + x + " your second number is " + y)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: You can easily format your print string using format, check my answer below to see how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
def takenum(x,y):
    print("Your first number is " + x + " your second number is " + y)
    result = (float(x) + float(y))
    print(result)

x = input("put your first number: " )
y = input("Put your second number: " )

takenum(x, y)
```

[image]

> NOTE: your input should be 3.5 not 3,6
>
> use dot as decimal separator

Or if you want use dots and commas or just commas as separator,
just remove the ,(comma) with replace():

```
def takenum(x,y):
    print("Your first number is " + x + " your second number is " + y)
    result = (float((x).replace(',','.')) + float((y).replace(',','.')))
    print(result)

x = input("put your first number: " )
y = input("Put your second number: " )

takenum(x, y)
```

what code is doing:

```
float((x).replace(',','.'))
```

you have x which is string(input is returning string), replace **,** (comma) with **.** (dot),and convert string into float

[image]

Comment: dude thank you so much i was going crazy about that little code thank you very much man

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad I helped :)

Comment: You know @ncica that you can just copy-paste your output instead of putting an image

Comment: tnx for advice @DeveshKumarSingh, in this case I just decided to put an image :)

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly convert your output to a float when you read it using `float(input())`, and then use string formatting to print it.

```
def takenum(x,y):
    print("Your first number is {} and your second number is {}".format(x, y))
    result = x + y
    print(result)

x = float(input("put your first number: " ))
y = float(input("Put your second number: " ))

takenum(x, y)
```

Your output will look like:

```
put your first number: 5.6
Put your second number: 6.5
Your first number is 5.6 and your second number is 6.5
12.1
```